# How Does it Change Touch Event Bool?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, touch-event

I want to check the touch events.But it doesn't work as i want.Where is my mistake?

The working example is like this.

```
      var boolChange = false;
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', () => boolChange = false, console.log(boolChange));
         //CONSOLE.LOG => false
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', () => boolChange = true, console.log(boolChange));
         //CONSOLE.LOG => false
      document.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
         if (boolChange) {
            alert("Working 1");
         }else {
            alert("Working 2");
         }
      });
```